# Retrieve Firestore collection data - Error -Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been working on Firestore for retrieving data, when I tried to get data from collection->document id-> field. refer the below screen shot, I need to check companyCode matches with user entered companyCode.text

[image]

I tried with below code, need to check whether the user entered companyCodeLabel.text matches document "companyCode" and also get documentId. Can anyone suggest how to solve this?

```
 guard let code = companyCodeLabel.text else { return }

let docRef = db.collection("Company").whereField("companyCode", isEqualTo: code).limit(to: 1)
docRef.getDocuments { (querysnapshot, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Document Error: ", error!)
    } else {
        if let doc = querysnapshot?.documents, !doc.isEmpty {
            print("Document is present.")
        }
    }
}
```

Even tried to print the field value in collection but still have crash and same error nil

```
self.db.collection("Company").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
          if let err = err {
              print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
          } else {
              for document in snapshot!.documents {
                 let docId = document.documentID
                 let compCode = document.get("companyCode") as! String
                 let compName = document.get("companyName") as! String

                 print(docId, compCode, compName)
              }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Debug your code. Set breakpoints. Watch veriables. Does `document` even contain what you expect?

Comment: @vadian it crashes straight away at first line of above two codes.

Comment: Once again: Debug your code.

Comment: Are you saying it crashes on this line? `guard let code = companyCodeLabel.text else { return }` as that's the first line. What is `self.db` or just `db`. Can you show us the error message as it appears in XCode - including the line it crashes on?

Comment: @Jay the crash doesnt come form guard let code = ...text,,,,,,,   let db = Firestore!, the crash is from first line of both code starting db.collection ... the crash message  is Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to call in wrong db, I was trying `var db = Firestore!`,

The correct solutions is

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("Company").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
          if let err = err {
              print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
          } else {
              for document in snapshot!.documents {
                 let docId = document.documentID
                 let compCode = document.get("companyCode") as! String
                 let compName = document.get("companyName") as! String

                 print(docId, compCode, compName)
              }
          }
```